# Set font universally for whole app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way I can declare the font size/name for the whole app instead of declaring it for every label/text etc I make?

Comment: Use `UIAppearance` here is a tutorial which will explain more https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

Obj-C

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:17.0]];
```

Swift

```
UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "YourFontName", size: 17.0)
```

Be sure to add your chosen font to your projects `target` if you're using a custom font.

Answer (score 1):

For example for `UILabel` instance you can achieve it with the following code, it uses `UIAppearance` API:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:15.0f]];
```

Put this code inside `AppDelegate` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Also don't forget to add your custom font name to your `Info.plist` file under `UIAppFonts` key-value pair.